# How to rotate all Collection's hierarchy in the Transform Panel in 2.80?

Tags: transforms

so I want to rotate all objects on one of my **Collection** (say 90-degree on the x-axis)... while I can do so manually through the Rotating tool...it's hard to get the exact **90-degree** value and too much time consuming.

So, I tried to just select the Collection or selected all the objects I want to rotate and try to rotate it through the Transform panel where I can just write 90 on the x-axis like you would on **Maya** or **C4D**... but the problem is that Blender won't let me do that, it just automatically select a sing;e object on all my selected objects or Collection and only rotate that single object.

So my question is, is there a way I can rotate multiple objects or all the objects under 1 Collection via Transform like in Maya or C4D?

*I mean, it's so intuitive when you think about it, idk why Blender haven't implemented this already... it's just weird, you know?*...that or it could be that I just couldn't figure out the "correct" way to go about it... if so then I apologize.

Comment: Just to be sure that there isn't a misunderstanding: Selecting several objects and then using R + X (to rotate around the x-axis) followed by typing 90, should rotate all objects by 90 degrees. If you want them to rotate around their individual origin instead of the median point of all selected objects, you can change the pivot point in the dropdown. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html

Comment: Oh wow, that actually do the trick, I didn't know you can just type a number after R+X... Thanks a bunch... I tried Ctrl+P to parent it then rotate it as a single object but sometime that new parent just take on a weird angle so eventhough I tried to rotate it by 90-degree, it ended up in a weird position... Anyway, thanks again.